# altering arcgis map location onClick in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering

I'm trying to update a map to my current location using a vue onClick which updates props and sends them to my map component. I am using a :key to rerender my map component when my map data changes and I get some new x,y for my map center. (based on the esri/arcgis example I would need to rebuild the map, if anyone knows this to be wrong let me know please)

VUE js arcgis starting documentation:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/vue/

for some reason my map does render again and seems like it's about to load but then it just stays blank.
maybe someone can tell me if this is an issue with the component still persisting in some way after I force it to render again?

my app.vue

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <web-map v-bind:centerX="lat" v-bind:centerY="long" ref="mapRef"/>

        <div class="center">
          <b-button class="btn-block" @click="getLocation" variant="primary">My Location</b-button>
        </div>
    </div>


</template>

<script>
import WebMap from './components/webmap.vue';

export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: { WebMap }, 
    data(){
      return{
        lat: -118,
        long: 34,
      }
    },
    methods:{

      showPos(pos){
        this.lat = pos.coords.latitude
        this.long = pos.coords.longitude

        this.$refs.mapRef.updateCoordinates()
        console.log('new location',this.lat,this.long, this.$refs)   
      },


      getLocation(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.showPos);
          } else { 
            console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
          }
      },

    },
};
</script>
```

my map component

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

export default {
  name: 'web-map',
  props:['centerX', 'centerY'],
  data: function(){
    return{
      X: this.centerX,
      Y: this.centerY,
      view: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('new data',this.X,this.Y)

    // lazy load the required ArcGIS API for JavaScript modules and CSS
    loadModules(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView'], { css: true })
    .then(([ArcGISMap, MapView]) => {
      const map = new ArcGISMap({
        basemap: 'topo-vector'
      });

      this.view = new MapView({
        container: this.$el,
        map: map,
        center: [this.X,this.Y],   ///USE PROPS HERE FOR NEW CENTER
        zoom: 8
      });
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.view) {
      // destroy the map view
      this.view.container = null;
    }
  },
  methods:{
    updateCoordinates(){
        this.view.centerAt([this.X,this.Y])
      }
  }

};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the key you're passing as a prop to `web-map` serves any purpose since it's not being used inside the component.

You could try, instead, to force update the component as such:

```
<web-map v-bind:centerX="lat" v-bind:centerY="long" ref="mapRef" />
```

```
this.refs.mapRef.$forceUpdate()
```

This ensures that you're force updating the whole component, but maybe there's a better solution. Instead of re-rendering the entire component, which means having to create the map once again, you could instead keep the component alive and just use an event to update the coordinates.

Based on https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/map-amd.html#centerat, you can re-center the map using the `centerAt` method.

That way the map component has a method like:

```
updateCoordinates(coord){
  this.view.centerAt(coord)
}
```

And you can call it on the parent with

```
this.refs.mapRef.updateCoordinates(newCenter)
```

Hope it helps, let me know if you do any progress.

Comment: I was able to utilize refs to access the component but now I get an error that this.view.centerAt is not a function. I'm supposing this is because 'this.view' as it refers to the map is coming back undefined. I'm not sure why this is. I will update my code to reflect my changes so far :)

Comment: Okay so I was able to get further using the view.goTo method as the view is considered a 'map view' and not a map so I had to find a different list of associated methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can test `Watch` with `setInterVal()` for a loop to check your location each 1sec

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I know that the location is correct and is updating, the map just tries to render again with the new coordinates and is blank for some reason. I think the issue is with the map itself for some reason